# How do I cleanup unwanted imgly overlays

Tags: android, photoeditorsdk

I am using PhotoSDK in android studio. I am wanting to reduce the size of my apk file and want to remove some of the unneeded files like in the drawable-nodpi-v4 folder.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After upgrading to V6 each module is listed so you can just comment out unused pieces in your Gradle file.